# Nexus 3: Groovy script imports (unable to locate CliBuilder class)

Tags: groovy, nexus

I am developing a parametrized Groovy script for Nexus 3.

I need to parse some parameters with the CliBuilder.

The problem is that the Groovy runtime of Nexus is not able to locate the CLIBuilder class.

Here is my script:

```
import groovy.cli.picocli.CliBuilder

CliBuilder  cli = new CliBuilder(
        usage: "groovy createFileBlobStore.groovy -n name -p path"
)

cli.with {
    n longOpt: 'name', args: 1, required: true, 'The name of the file blob store'
    p longOpt: 'path', args: 1, required: true, 'The path of the file blob store'
}

def options = cli.parse(args)
if (!options) {
    return
}

String blobStoreName = options.n
String blobStorePath = options.p

if (!blobStore.blobStoreManager.exists(blobStoreName)) {
    blobStore.createFileBlobStore(blobStoreName, blobStorePath)
}
```

I have also read that this is now available by default in Groovy but it doesn't seem to work.

How do I import this dependency in the Nexus Goovy?

Comment: "I have also read that this is now available by default in Groovy but it doesn't seem to work." - In which version(s) of Groovy is it believed to be available by default?

Comment: It seems from Groovy 3 considering also the second link date.

https://docs.groovy-lang.org/3.0.8/html/gapi/groovy/cli/picocli/CliBuilder.html

https://opensource.com/article/21/8/parsing-command-options-groovy

Comment: Which version of Groovy is in use in your environment?

Comment: By logging `GroovySystem.version` I get 2.4.17

Comment: See also https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-public/blob/917be655dbd92d38ef14638cc3a2b0d52a855a7d/pom.xml#L637

Comment: and https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-public/blob/917be655dbd92d38ef14638cc3a2b0d52a855a7d/pom.xml#L632